# Notice: Use of undefined constant USER_SESSION - assumed 'USER_SESSION'

Tags: php, if-statement, constants, session-cookies

I have this error in these line:

```
public static function isLogged()
{
    if(USER_SESSION)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Declaration:

```
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
         define('USER_SESSION',         $_SESSION['username']);
```

Comment: error message is pretty clear, USER_SESSION **is not** defined **when** you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`defined()`](http://php.net/defined) to checks that the constant exists, otherwise you will get a notice ([E_NOTICE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php#errorfunc.constants.errorlevels.e-notice)) in situations where you constant is not defined.

```
if( defined('USER_SESSION') ) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Yeap, definitely. The constant `USER_SESSION` which was referred to `$_SESSION['username']` wasn't `boolean` to be `if`ed like that.

Comment: @iamsleepy Yes, it's not a boolean. But no, this is not the reason why he gets the notice, PHP can `if` anything, anything that results in a `TRUE` if given to `empty()` will be evaluated to `FALSE` when `if`ed. See [documentation for `empty()`](http://php.net/empty).

Comment: sorry totally forgot about that. Now I remember everything that is not empty,`NULL` or 0 in value will be evaluated as `TRUE` unless strict comparator is used.

Comment: @iamsleepy, variables that contain `null`, `0`, `""`, `array()`... ARE empty; so if you evaluate them, them will evaluate to FALSE.